# Electron and angularJS app architecture - SPA clone in two windows

Tags: angularjs, architecture, electron

In **mainWindow** of my application I have angularJS SPA. Everything is fine untill I create **new** window. In every window I need to loadURL which is path to HTML document like in **mainWindow**:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 790,
    height: 580
});
mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'), // load - index.html angularjs dashboard
    slashes: true
}));
```

Problem is that since I have SPA in my **mainWindow** after I open **new** window I should load entire SPA to **new** window as well as in **mainWindow** and just redirect to correct (hidden) url so I would have some other content in this new one. I would need to load this entire SPA in order to have access to my SPA services, factories and directives which I need to use in **new** window.

```
let createQuestionWindow = () => {
    questionWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 380,
        height: 300,
        alwaysOnTop: true
    });
    transparentWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
    // in above line im actually loading same SPA as in mainWindow
    questionWindow.isFocused();
    questionWindow.setFocusable(true);
    mainWindow.restore();
    // here I should also redirect or set url somehow but...
};
createQuestionWindow();
```

I'm not even trying to set correct url in clone SPA in **new** window because it'll probably cause huge performance issues because in the end I would have open 2 or even 3 sometimes windows which would be exact same clones of SPA.

That's not very good solution [I heard about "child window"](https://electronjs.org/docs/all#parent-and-child-windows) but still it doesn't provide me ability to access parent SPA ( I think ).

How to refactor my application so I'll be able to access SPA from **new** windows but I'll do not need to load entire thing again and again?

If that's not possible to accomplish in other, better way then how to set url of SPA in **new** window from electron (node) side of app but in the way that angularJS router will catch it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that is the drawback of electron windows architecture: each window is like a separate Chrome browser, with its own process. Therefore it has to reload all its HTML, JS and CSS, without being able to re-use (memory-wise) whatever was in another window.

In the case of an SPA (Single Page Application), yeah that definitely means reloading your whole SPA in the new window, even if you had all the code to render your new window content in your previous window.

It is a very similar case as trying to open a view of your SPA in a popup browser window. See [How can I render an Angular directive in a popup window, allow it to communicate with the main window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900361/how-can-i-render-an-angular-directive-in-a-popup-window-allow-it-to-communicate)

Electron child windows will not be of any help either. The concept of "child" window is only to make sure the user cannot display the "parent" window in front of the "child" before the latter is closed. But the child window still has to load its own assets.

Of course you could simply resort to avoid using new windows, and use some modals or traditional routing within your main window (very much like a normal browser web app).

But if you really want to benefit from electron and the desktop app experience by opening new windows, then there is usually not such a hard time reloading your entire SPA in the latters. On the contrary of a web app, all your assets are locally available and they load quickly (unless you do have a MB size app…)

Now as to how to open the new window to a specific URL / route, simply configure your router to use a hash scheme, so that you can write your URL to open your common `index.html` file but with a route passed as the hash part, e.g.:

```
newWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html#!/question`);
```

Then your router will automatically catch it when the SPA loads in the new window, and display the corresponding view.

See for example:

- [Blank screen when navigating Angular routes within Electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962182/blank-screen-when-navigating-angular-routes-within-electron-app)
- https://discuss.atom.io/t/angular-ngroute-not-working/32605

Comment: This 2 SPAs ( mainWindow and newWindow ) can communicate? Can I send custom event from newWindow and catch it mainWindow? So I would be able to create one small SPA only sending some events

Comment: Like for any other electron application, you should use IPC communication, through the main process. It should be trivial to set up the main process as a tunnel to redirect the messages to your renderers.